# Postgresql coalesce columns with JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, coalesce

Let's say that we have the following JSON object:

```
{"key_to_array":[{"key1":"value1","key2":{"var123":{"xyz":"I_need_version_1"}}},{"key1":"value1","key2":{"htg":{"uy1":"I_need_version_2"}}}]}}
```

inserted into a table:

```
drop table if exists modeling.modeling.pl_nested_json_array;
select '{"key_to_array":[{"key1":"value1","key2":{"var123":{"xyz":"I_need_version_1"}}},{"key1":"value1","key2":{"htg":{"uy1":"I_need_version_2"}}}]}' as json_data
into modeling.modeling.pl_nested_json_array
from modeling.modeling.some_other_table
limit 1;
```

In order to get to the `I_need_version_*` I must travel semi-constant way. 'Semi' means that some elements are varying (keys: `var123`, `xyz`, `htg`, `uy1`). There is a finite number of their combinations so I can handle them by writing different ways in my code such as:

```
json_array_elements(cast(json_data as json) -> 'key_to_array') -> 'key2' -> 'var123' ->> 'xyz' as col1
```

The problem is that my current approach:

```
/* many columns version - unwanted */
select 
    json_array_elements(cast(json_data as json) -> 'key_to_array') ->> 'key1' as key1,
    json_array_elements(cast(json_data as json) -> 'key_to_array') -> 'key2' -> 'var123' ->> 'xyz' as col1,
    json_array_elements(cast(json_data as json) -> 'key_to_array') -> 'key2' -> 'htg' ->> 'uy1' as col2
from modeling.modeling.pl_nested_json_array;
```

produces as many columns as there are ways to get to `I_need_version_*`. Since for each `JSON_data` only one way is valid (produces `I_need_version_*`) the rest of the columns `col*` are NULL, I decided to use `COALESCE()` in order to get one column `col` with the non-NULL value:

```
select 
    json_array_elements(cast(json_data as json) -> 'key_to_array') ->> 'key1' as key1,
    coalesce(
    json_array_elements(cast(json_data as json) -> 'key_to_array') -> 'key2' -> 'var123' ->> 'xyz',
    json_array_elements(cast(json_data as json) -> 'key_to_array') -> 'key2' -> 'htg' ->> 'uy1') as col
from modeling.modeling.pl_nested_json_array;
```

Upon executing this query I get `ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in COALESCE`.

The output I'm currently getting:

```
key1          col1               col2
value1        I_need_version_1   [NULL]
value1        [NULL]             I_need_version_2
```

What I'd like to get:

```
key1     col
value1   I_need_version_1
value1   I_need_version_2
```

Comment: It is [always] possible to nest the select as a derived query and coalesce the first output to the second: `SELECT COALESCE(t.col1, t.col2) FROM (SELECT .. FROM table ..) t`.

Comment: That said, the 'correct' approach is probably to ensure a scalar is supplied to coalesce..

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've tested your solution on my minimal reproducible example and it works. The problem (or rather inconvenience) is that the original table `t` from has some a lot of columns. If your solution is the only one feasible I'm willing to use but other that handle the problem directly are also welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just fully expanding the json and picking out the elements that you need?  I'm not sure how many rows we're talking about, so performance could be an issue, but at least you wouldn't need to worry about the different paths.

```
WITH data as (
  SELECT '{"key_to_array":[{"key1":"value1","key2":{"var123":{"xyz":"I_need_version_1"}}},{"key1":"value1","key2":{"htg":{"uy1":"I_need_version_2"}}}]}'::jsonb as data
)
SELECT key1, k3_val
FROM data
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data.data -> 'key_to_array') arr(elem)
CROSS JOIN jsonb_to_record(elem) as x(key1 text, key2 jsonb)
CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(key2) as k2(k2_key, k2_val)
CROSS JOIN jsonb_each_text(k2_val) as k3(k3_key, k3_val)
WHERE k3_val like 'I_need_version_%'
;
key1    k3_val
value1  I_need_version_1
value1  I_need_version_2
```